# Firebase Cloud Functions - context params reference brings error: firestoreInstance.settings is not a function at snapshotConstructor

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Given simple function; if I merely console log "context" I get a log back with the parameters in tow, but if I specifically console log (or otherwise reference) a single parameter as per the example below, I am presented with this `firestoreInstance.settings` error. If anyone can point me in the right direction please I'd appreciate it.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp();

exports.newNotification = functions.firestore
.document('/messages/{senderUsername}/threads/{recipientUsername}/lines/{docId}')
.onCreate((snap, context) => {
  const message = snap.data();
  const sender = context.params.senderUsername;
  const recipient = context.params.recipientUsername;
  console.log('Notifying', message, sender, recipient); 
});
```

Error as follows:

[image: Firestore / Firebase Cloud Functions error response]

**EDIT---**
So it appears to be intermittent. I fired off a message and then waited and fired off another - one returned the error, the other returned the desired result.

[image: intermittent error]

Maybe it's linked to timestamps (server timestamps)?

**EDIT--**

So I've changed the code to the following:

```
exports.newNotification = functions.firestore.document('/messages/{senderUsername}/threads/{recipientUsername}/lines/{docId}')
.onCreate((snap, context) => {
  const message = snap.data();
  const sender = context.params.senderUsername;
  const recipient = context.params.recipientUsername;
  console.log('Notifying', message, sender, recipient);
  const deviceRef = admin.firestore().doc(`/devices/${recipient}`);
  deviceRef.get().then(doc => {
    const val = doc.data();
    const payload = {
      notification: {
        title: 'New Message!',
        body: `${sender}: ${message.msg}`
      }
    };
    const token = val.token;
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload);
  }).catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

And it appears we're back to the errors again - occasionally one goes through successfully. Could delays in backgrounding / prolonged observer subscription cause issues like this?

Here's the console log of the context, as a comment requested:

[image: successful context inbetween intermittent operation]

For the record, I tried deleting the token in between messages and that was caught as it should be. I added some characters at the start of the device token and it returned the usual error - I will continue testing, maybe if the token is invalid and requires renewal this is the error you get?

**EDIT--**

My uninformed conclusion would be that there's a cold start on functions before they are formalised in some sort of caching method - and maybe I am getting the intermittent errors due to testing in between those "solidification" moments. As you can see it goes from error to delayed to pretty much instant. Still would love some clarity on the subject if someone in-the-know has some.

[image: Intermittent Firebase function responses]

**EDIT--**

I have found that if time lapses the working function can die, then it appears to be brought back from the dead and can be a bit of a sluggish zombie before it feeds on more of your executions and becomes healthy again:

[image: lazerus]

Comment: Can you also provide the output of your context log?

Comment: The very first attempt usually shows up this error, in one case I had it fallback to a previous function update after the error and then proceed with the latest function update. So perhaps it's just a matter of function caching and function updating where this error can occur. If anyone can confirm I'll give the answer

Comment: It's definitely something on Firebase's end... not mine - I just ran it and it executed fine, then I ran it again less than a minute apart and got the error again: firestoreInstance.settings is not a function

Comment: I also face the same problem - after deploying functions it fails for the first time it is triggered. Then it works fine. It is very annoying and it can cause us serious problems.

Comment: @Tomas and Grant You may create an issue at https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: Thanks @RenaudTarnec I just lodged a support request, hopefully a member of the team can explain why this is happening for us to understand.

Comment: I got the same problem as well !

Comment: I have noticed that if an amount of time lapses between executions of the function this error pops up again, even if it was working fine before, then after the second or third attempt it resumes normal functionality --- until the next lapse in use. Hopefully the team at Google can shed some light on this for us soon. @musecz

Comment: As a workaround I created a scheduled task which triggers all my functions every 10 minutes in order to avoid cold start.

Comment: This occurred to me too, @Tomas - it would be nice to know this is simply how Firestore works; for the sake of cost effectiveness or storage conservation - whatever it may be. I will keep this thread updated with any feedback I get from Google.

Comment: @Tomas has that scheduled task kept your functions alive successfully? If so, can you share how you did it and I'll accept that as the answer for now

Comment: @Grant it used to work few days ago, but since today it does not work again. I used this solution for scheduled tasks: https://github.com/firebase/functions-cron

Answer (score 3):

After updating firebase-admin to the latest version (5.13.1) it's working correctly. It seems that firebase-functions v2 need firebase-admin version 5.13.0 or above !

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using firebase-admin 5.13.1 and still experiencing the issue. Your function never has a cold start or dies?

Comment: What is your version of firebase-functions ? Yeah I have cold start but I do not have the firestoreInstance.settings error anymore

Comment: I had firebase-admin 5.12 with firebase-functions v2, after upgrading firebase-admin to 5.13.1 I don't get the error. Thanks a lot!

Comment: thanks a lot it wokre for me i wrote npm install firebase-functions@latest --save
npm install firebase-admin@latest --save-exact in my functions folder then also typed this in my cmd and it worked well thank you for people new to firebase like me read this i just did what they told here>>>>https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff